# How do I prevent PHP from stripping my Slashes of my background-image CSS statement?

Tags: php, html

So I have been struggling for at least an hour now.

I have this code:

```
if($type == 'p'){
            echo '<div class="post" style="top: '.$spacing.'px;">
                    <a href="'.$source.'"><div class="postwrapper">
                        <div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url("http://localhost/varea/media/thumbnails/'.$postid.'.jpg")"></div>
                        <div class="info">
                            <div class="title">'.$title.'</div>
                            <div class="pdesc">
                                <p>Likes: '.$likes.'</p>
                                <p>Dislikes: '.$dislikes.'</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="underline"></div>
                    </div></a>
                </div>';
        }
```

But when I load the Page the "/" get stripped and my css statement looks like this:

```
<div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url(" http:="" localhost="" media="" thumbnails="" 2.jpg");"=""></div>
```

So how do I tell php to stop removing the slashes?

Comment: The slashes are there, view the real source. Your developer console is correcting the mark up errors.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same quotation marks for multiple purposes:

```
<div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url("http://localhost/varea/media/thumbnails/'.$postid.'.jpg")"></div>
                             ^                      ^
                             open                  close
```

Try using `\'` (so it doesn't close your echo) or something of that kind instead.

Maybe this will work for you:

```
if($type == 'p'){
            echo '<div class="post" style="top: '.$spacing.'px;">
                    <a href="'.$source.'"><div class="postwrapper">
                        <div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url(\'http://localhost/varea/media/thumbnails/'.$postid.'.jpg\')"></div>
                        <div class="info">
                            <div class="title">'.$title.'</div>
                            <div class="pdesc">
                                <p>Likes: '.$likes.'</p>
                                <p>Dislikes: '.$dislikes.'</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="underline"></div>
                    </div></a>
                </div>';
        }
```

Comment: I just found the solution.It works without the "". Thanks tho.